# What's wrong in touch listener Android

Tags: android, touch, android-canvas

I am working on canvas and able to complete the graphic part of a dial and placed some apps on the dial (just like older telephone) and now I want to identify on which icon the user has touched. I have implemented this code for this in touch listener:

```
public class CanvasDemActivity extends Activity {

Bitmap mLight,mDial,mBrowser,mCamera,mMessage,mDialer,mHome,mLock;
float angle;
ArrayList<Double> mCurrentAngleArray;
ArrayList<PointF> mArray; 
ArrayList<Bitmap> mBitmapArray;
PointF p1,p2,p3,p4,p5;
String mTIme;
Date date;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // making it full screen
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    Dialer view = new Dialer(this);
    setContentView(view);

    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int action = event.getAction();

if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
PointF p = new PointF();
   p.x = event.getX(); p.y = event.getY();

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
if (p.x >= mArray.get(i).x && p.x < (mArray.get(i).x + mBitmapArray.get(i).getWidth())
        && p.y >= mArray.get(i).y && p.y < (mArray.get(i).y + mBitmapArray.get(i).getHeight())) {
    System.out.println("presssed on icon " + i);
    break;
    }

}
return true;
}

}

public class Dialer extends View{

    Context mcontext;
    public Dialer(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mcontext = context;

        mLight = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mcontext.getResources(), R.drawable.light);
        mDial = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mcontext.getResources(), R.drawable.dial);
        mBrowser = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mcontext.getResources(), R.drawable.browser);
        mCamera = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mcontext.getResources(), R.drawable.camera);
        mMessage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mcontext.getResources(), R.drawable.message);
        mDialer = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mcontext.getResources(), R.drawable.dialer);
        mHome = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mcontext.getResources(), R.drawable.home);
        mLock = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mcontext.getResources(), R.drawable.lock);

        mArray = new ArrayList<PointF>();
        mBitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        mCurrentAngleArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
        mBitmapArray.add(mBrowser);
        mBitmapArray.add(mCamera);
        mBitmapArray.add(mMessage);
        mBitmapArray.add(mDialer);
        mBitmapArray.add(mHome);

        date = new Date();

        p1 = new PointF();
        p1.x = 80.0f ; p1.y = 475;
        mArray.add(p1);

        p2 = new PointF();
        p2.x = 120.0f ; p2.y = 320.0f;
        mArray.add(p2);

        p3 = new PointF();
        p3.x = 260 ; p3.y = 275;
        mArray.add(p3);

        p4 = new PointF();
        p4.x = 315 ; p4.y = 390;
        mArray.add(p4);

        p5 = new PointF();
        p5.x = 330 ; p5.y = 460;
        mArray.add(p5);

        float delta_x,delta_y;
        double mCurrentAngle;

        for(int i=0; i<5 ; i++) {
            delta_x = mArray.get(i).x - 248;
            delta_y = mArray.get(i).y - 430;
            mCurrentAngle = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
            mCurrentAngleArray.add(mCurrentAngle);
        }

    }


    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(75);



        if(date.getMinutes() > 9)
             mTIme = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
        else
            mTIme = date.getHours() + ":0" + date.getMinutes();

        canvas.drawText(mTIme, 140,125, paint);

        String dayNames[] = new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays();
        Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        String day =  dayNames[date2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)];

        java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        String  properformat = day+", "+ date.getDate() + " " +new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(d);
        paint.setTextSize(25);

        canvas.drawText(properformat, 125, 175, paint);


        TelephonyManager telephonyManager =((TelephonyManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
        String operatorName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
        if(operatorName.length() == 0 )
            operatorName = "Insert Sim Card";

        paint.setTextSize(20);
        canvas.drawText(operatorName, 175, 210, paint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mDial, canvas.getWidth()/10, canvas.getHeight()/4, null);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mLock, canvas.getWidth()/10, canvas.getHeight()/4, null);

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            double X = 120 * Math.cos(mCurrentAngleArray.get(i) + angle);
            double Y = 120 * Math.sin(mCurrentAngleArray.get(i) + angle);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapArray.get(i),210 + (float) X, 395+ (float)Y, null);
        }
        angle = angle + 0.01f;

        canvas.drawBitmap(mLight, canvas.getWidth()/9,canvas.getHeight()/4f, null);

        invalidate();
    }

}
```

}

where p.x and p.y are the user touched coordinates and mArray is the coordinates where I have placed the bitmaps and mBitmapArray is the arraylist where I have stored bitmap.

The problem is that even though I have written the code correctly, I am unable to get into the "if" condition when I am pressing browser and dialer icons.
I have tested the same code in a sample app and it works fine.
Can you please tell me what's the problem?

Comment: A bit more code would be useful. I assume you are using a loop? Can you post the surrounding code as well?

Comment: @jsydow:yes I am having for loop as well and i have updated above

Comment: I would investigate more using LogCat. What are the coordinates that you receive from the MotionEvent and where are the coordinates of the images and the images width. I do not see anything that is wrong with the if-clause itself so i think the problem are the values. By logging all values you should get a picture of where the values are wrong or misinterpreted. For example the touch event coordinates should be relative to the view of the onTouchListener not relative to the screen or something like that.

Comment: @JSydow:I have attached the code completely and i have found that touch is working for some icons only